# Populist badge when accepted answer has negative score

Tags: discussion, answers, badges, accepted-answer

This question was inspired by [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285972/how-to-find-if-a-suspicious-account-down-votes-your-posts/285981#285981), and the definition of the [**Populist Badge**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/populist):

> Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Can you get the populist badge if the score of the accepted answer is negative?  Mathematically speaking, your score would have to be negative in order to double the accepted answer's score, simultaneously being ten higher, which is impossible.

Does this mean that someone could be on the way to getting the populist badge (say accepted answer has score of 1, they have a score of 10 on their answer) and miss it totally because the accepted answer gets a downvote or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the accepted answer needs to have a score of 11 or more, and therefore your own answer a score of at least 23.

> Does this mean that someone could be on the way to getting the populist badge ... and miss it totally because the accepted answer gets a downvote or two?

That can still happen, if the accepted answer's score drops from 11 to a lower number.

Comment: Ah, I'm misunderstanding the definition, then.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I've understood now.  The unclear brief definition does now make sense.